# unset array keys based on comparing two array values in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to remove/unset duplicate array values based off a higher secondary value in the array in **php**.

**Here's an simple example of the original array.**

```
$ar = array(
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'26.00','promo_id'=>'9807'),
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'15.00','promo_id'=>'9821'),
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'21.00','promo_id'=>'9811'),
    array('pid'=>'2965','discount'=>'25.00','promo_id'=>'9810'),
    array('pid'=>'2965','discount'=>'30.50','promo_id'=>'9809'),
    array('pid'=>'1866','discount'=>'30.00','promo_id'=>'9810'),
    array('pid'=>'1866','discount'=>'25.50','promo_id'=>'9809')
);
```

**This would be the NEW array that I would like to get.**

```
$ar = array(
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'26.00','promo_id'=>'9807'),
    array('pid'=>'2965','discount'=>'30.50','promo_id'=>'9809'),
    array('pid'=>'1866','discount'=>'30.00','promo_id'=>'9810'),
);
```

**These would be the keys that have been removed.**

```
//array('pid'=>'1866','discount'=>'25.50','promo_id'=>'9809')  Removed!
//array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'21.00','promo_id'=>'9811'), Removed!
//array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'15.00','promo_id'=>'9821'), Removed!
//array('pid'=>'2965','discount'=>'25.00','promo_id'=>'9810'), Removed!
```

I would like to remove any duplicate values of the `'pid'` by **KEEPING** the highest value of the `'discount'`.

The array may have more than two keys that have the same `'pid'` but they would never have the same `'pid'` and `'promo_id'`.

Hopefully there is an easy solution for this.

EDIT:

Here what I've been trying.

```
foreach($ar as $tkey => $v) {

    $tPID = $v['pid'];
    $tDISC = $v['discount'];

    if ($tPID) {

        $key = array_search($tPID, array_column($ar, 'pid'));
        $aPID  = $ar[$key]['pid'];
        $aTPRD = $ar[$key]['discount'];

        if ($aTPRD < $tDISC) {
            echo '(UN:'.$tkey.')'; unset($ar[$tkey]);
        }else
        if ($aTPRD > $tDISC) {
            echo '(UN:'.$key.')'; unset($ar[$key]);
        }else{echo 'else'; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-ukey.php. You can write a callback and compare pid in it.

Comment: I only have 1 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an output array, keyed on 'pid' that holds the highest discount entry found for the pid.

Extract the output array using 'array_values'.

[Working code at Codepad.org...](http://codepad.org/fbX90qGe)

There was a suggested edit to the code to make it shorter.
However, i try to ensure the code is easy to understand rather than try and make it the minimum amount of code. This code is quite efficient as it is anyway.

```
 <?php //

$ar = array(
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'26.00','promo_id'=>'9807'),
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'15.00','promo_id'=>'9821'),
    array('pid'=>'544', 'discount'=>'21.00','promo_id'=>'9811'),
    array('pid'=>'2965','discount'=>'25.00','promo_id'=>'9810'),
    array('pid'=>'2965','discount'=>'30.50','promo_id'=>'9809'),
    array('pid'=>'1866','discount'=>'30.00','promo_id'=>'9810'),
    array('pid'=>'1866','discount'=>'25.50','promo_id'=>'9809')
);

$outUnique = array();

foreach ($ar as $entry) {

    $curPid = $entry['pid'];

    if (isset($outUnique[$curPid])) { // check the discount

        if ($entry['discount'] > $outUnique[$curPid]['discount']) {
            $outUnique[$curPid] = $entry;
        }
    }
    else { // add to the output

        $outUnique[$curPid] = $entry;
    }
}
// show the entries
var_dump(array_values($outUnique));
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks for that, its much more simple than I was making it.