# Merging two arrays keeping one version of merged element according to its properties

Tags: php, arrays

I have three array as bellow :

```
    $one = array (
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP1',
            'product_code' => 'ITM001',
            'product' => 'Book',
            'price' => '5500',
        ),
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP1',
            'product_code' => 'ITM002',
            'product' => 'Pencil',
            'price' => '1500',
        ),
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP1',
            'product_code' => 'ITM002',
            'product' => 'Eraser',
            'price' => '1750',
        ),
    )

    $two = array (
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP2',
            'product_code' => 'SP001',
            'product' => 'Book',
            'price' => '5250',
        ),
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP2',
            'product_code' => 'SP002',
            'product' => 'Pencil',
            'price' => '1550',
        ),
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP2',
            'product_code' => 'SP002',
            'product' => 'Ruler',
            'price' => '2300',
        ),
    )

    $three = array (
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP3',
            'product_code' => 'BRG01',
            'product' => 'Book',
            'price' => '5250',
        ),
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP3',
            'product_code' => 'BRG02',
            'product' => 'Ruler',
            'price' => '2350',
        ),
        array (
            'supplier_name' => 'SUP3',
            'product_code' => 'BRG02',
            'product' => 'Drawing book',
            'price' => '4500',
        ),
    )
```

I have already merge all above array with array_merge.

```
$all_array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP1',
    'product_code' => 'ITM001',
    'product' => 'Book',
    'price' => '5500',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP1',
    'product_code' => 'ITM002',
    'product' => 'Pencil',
    'price' => '1500',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP1',
    'product_code' => 'ITM002',
    'product' => 'Eraser',
    'price' => '1750',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP2',
    'product_code' => 'SP001',
    'product' => 'Book',
    'price' => '5250',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP2',
    'product_code' => 'SP002',
    'product' => 'Pencil',
    'price' => '1550',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP2',
    'product_code' => 'SP002',
    'product' => 'Ruler',
    'price' => '2300',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP3',
    'product_code' => 'BRG01',
    'product' => 'Book',
    'price' => '5250',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP3',
    'product_code' => 'BRG02',
    'product' => 'Ruler',
    'price' => '2350',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'supplier_name' => 'SUP3',
    'product_code' => 'BRG02',
    'product' => 'Drawing book',
    'price' => '4500',
  ),
)
```

How can I remove duplicate  with higher value and only get lower price of all items.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supplier_name] => SUP2
            [product_code] => SP001
            [product] => Book
            [price] => 5250
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supplier_name] => SUP1
            [product_code] => ITM002
            [product] => Pencil
            [price] => 1500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [supplier_name] => SUP1
            [product_code] => ITM002
            [product] => Eraser
            [price] => 1750
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [supplier_name] => SUP2
            [product_code] => SP002
            [product] => Ruler
            [price] => 2300
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [supplier_name] => SUP3
            [product_code] => BRG02
            [product] => Drawing book
            [price] => 4500
        )

)
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your items haven't unique key (more than one product can have the same `supplier_name` and the same `product_code`). It will be less painful to have a unique key for each product, your problem will become way easier to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using PHP. Although it would be way better and less painful to have your products mapped with a unique named key, here's a way to solve your problem.

Don't use array_merge since it doesn't allow you to use a callback to keep only the cheaper product.

Here is a pseudo-code you could use (rather than untested php I would provide). Adapt it to your source code.

```or-tag-here
// Everything has a beginning.
array_result = array()

// Browsing array1
For each item of array1
    found_item = false
    // For each product of array1, seeking for the same product in array2
    For each item2 of array2
        If areTheSameProduct(item1, item2)
            If item1.price < item2.price Then
                appendToArray(array_result, item1)
            Else
                appendToArray(array_result, item2)
            End If
            found_item = true
            // Removing then the product in array2, to let at the end only
            // the ones which was't found in array1.
            // In PHP, use here unset() to remove an element from the array.
            // "key" parameter can be a named index or the classic integer one
            unset(array1[key of item2])
            Break // No need to continue the loop on array2
        End If
    End For
    // Item not found in array2? We'll keep the one of array1.
    If (Not found_item) Then appendToArray(array_result, item1)
End For

// For the remaining values of array_two (which were not in array1)
For each item2 of array2
  appendToArray(array_result, item2 )
End For

// Comparator function
Function areTheSameProduct(item1, item2)
    return (item1.supplier_name == item2.supplier_name) AND
           (item1.product_code  == item2.product_code) AND
           (item1.product       == item2.product)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I have already get solution for my case in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906861/unset-array-keys-based-on-comparing-two-array-values-in-the-same-array(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906861/unset-array-keys-based-on-comparing-two-array-values-in-the-same-array)

Comment: The solution you linked uses named keys (`$outUnique[$curPid] = $entry;`) to fill the result array. :) As said before, maybe you should use them to store your products, a key for one product. (The link you pasted is misformatted.)